# 95th and 99th percentile latency

Tags: database, performance, statistics, latency, percentile

I am measuring database performance and am looking at p95 and p99 latency.
My results are as follows.

Database A shows:

```
95thPercentileLatency(ms)   20
99thPercentileLatency(ms)   28
```

Database B shows:

```
95thPercentileLatency(ms)   1
99thPercentileLatency(ms)   3
```

I understand that the 99th percentile latency indicates that 99% of operations completed in under a given latency, so for database B `3`

I am unsure of the significance of 1 system having a 99th and 95th percentile latency that are very close to each other, and another where they are much further apart. What does this mean?

Comment: One of them has the 99th percentile at 3 times the value of the 95th percentile; the other has it at 40% above.  The bigger question to me would be "why is the Database A so much slower than Database B", rather than worrying about the difference between 2 ms and 8 ms delay time.  Also, is there a problem?  If the requirement is that 99th percentile should be under 1 second, then both systems are performing admirably.  If the requirement is that the 99th percentile should be under 10 ms, you have problems in A and not in B.